# What would be the correct way to average standard scores in order to account for variance?

Tags: statistics, variance

I have a set of standard scores and would like to find an overall average. If I just add them up and divide by the total number of scores I am not taking into account the variance right? How can I go about getting an overall average of the scores?

Comment: why would you want to account for the variance in the average?

Comment: There are many, many different measurements of "average", depending on what qualities you are looking for.   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_tendency